# Eliminate duplicate pairs of numbers and total their quantities in openoffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a Calc sheet listing a cut-list for plywood in two columns with a quantity in a third column. I would like to remove duplicate matching pairs of dimensions and total the quantity. Starting with:

A   B   C
25  35  2
25  40  1
**25  45  3**
**25  45  2**
35  45  1
35  50  3
**40  25  1

40  25  1**

Ending with:

A   B   C
25  35  2
25  40  1
**25  45  5**
35  45  1
35  50  3
**40  25  2**

I'm trying to automate this. Currently I have multiple lists which occupy the same page which need to be totaled independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique different ListId, ListCode or ListNumber for each of the lists. Let all rows falling into the same list, have the same value for this field.

Concatenate A & B and form a new column, say, PairAB. 
If the list is small and handlable, filter for PairAB and collect totals. 
Otherwise, use Grouping and subtotals to get totals for each list and each pair, grouping on ListId and PairAB.

If the list is very large, you are better off taking it to CSV, and onward to a database, such things are simple child's play in SQL.